# Local DNS server is ignored on Windows

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, openvpn, nameserver, internal-dns

I've setup dnsmasq on a Linux box and setup the DNS address on another Linux by adding its IP to `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.9.105
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Now I can ping to any internal ip, as follows:

```
$ ping cca
PING cca (192.168.9.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cca-erik (192.168.9.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms
64 bytes from cca-erik (192.168.9.102): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
^C
--- cca ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.017/0.020/0.024/0.005 ms
```

However, on Windows I'm having some issues. I set the nameserver as follows:

```
netsh interface ip set dns name="aea-tap" static 192.168.9.105
ipconfig /flushdns
```

nslookup seems to resolve a domain name correctly:

```
C:\Users\cca>nslookup cca
Server:   aktos-1-vpn
Address:  192.168.9.105

Name:     cca
Address:  192.168.9.102
```

But ping doesn't work:

```
C:\Users\cca>ping cca
Ping request could not find host cca. Please check the name and try again.
```

How can I fix this on Windows so I can `ping cca`?

Comment: Have you added the DNS suffix on the address in Windows? Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings -> Adapter Properties -> Internet Protocol Version 4 Properties -> Advanced -> DNS -> DNS suffix for this connection; Register this connection's addresses in DNS; Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `dnsmasq` as your DHCP server, you can push the DNS domain, DNS search list, and router to the clients.  This should resolve your issue.

```
dhcp-option=3,192.0.2.1             # Router
dhcp-option=6,192.0.2.              # DNS servers
dhcp-option=15,example.com          # Domain
dhcp-option=119,example.com,com,org # Domain search list (clients may not support)
```

If you have neither a domain nor a search list, then the address searched for would be `cca`.  This is unlikely to ever have an IP address.

However, if you have a netbios name server serving the name, this would be a valid address.  `ping cca` would likely work on Windows in this case.

The standby is to configure the name and IP in `/etc/hosts`.  Windows relocates the file, but still uses it.

Comment: No, the DHCP server is not under my control, it's all done by OpenVPN server itself and I'm not sure if I can control it or not...

Comment: Well, I got dnsmasq working as my DHCP server. When I try to connect to vpn, the dnsmasq assigns an ip from specified range. Now `nslookup cca 192.168.9.105` also fails on Windows, even the same command runs successfully on Linux.